# Vavr try fold want an exception in the first argument

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, graphql, vavr

I use GraphQL with Vavr.

In the first function argument, the Try.fold is waiting to raise an exception but in my case, I want to return a DataFetcherResult.

When compiling, I get the following error

```
Object / Required type: DataFetcherResult<Result>
```

when compiling the line
`vehicle -> DataFetcherResult.newResult().data(vehicle).build()`.

```java
public DataFetcherResult<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
     return vehicleService.getVehicle()
        .fold(
            // Error because doesn't throw return an exception
            exception -> DataFetcherResult.newResult().error(new CustomGraphqlException(exception)),
            vehicle -> DataFetcherResult.newResult().data(vehicle).build()
        );
}
```

`vehicleService.getVehicle()` returns Try of Vehicle.

```java
public Try<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
    return Try.of(() -> buildVehicle().stream().findFirst().get());
}
```

How I can recover from a `Try<Vehicle>`, a `DataFetcher` in the case of a success and in the case of an error ?

Comment: "My code doesn't compile" is not descriptive enough. Can you edit your Question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimalreproducible-example), so anyone can try to compile this?

Comment: Thanks Scratte, I tried to be more clearer